# DLL load failed when importing TensorFlow with GPU support

Tags: windows, tensorflow, installation

I am trying to install TensorFlow with GPU support on Windows 10, but I get an error (shown below) when importing it. The CPU version works fine.

I have

- installed `tensorflow-gpu` through pip
- updated the NVidia drivers for my GTX 1050 with GeForce Experience
- installed CUDA 10.1 with NVidia's network installer
- [installed cuDNN](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#installwindows) 7.5.0.56, taking care of copying every file in the right CUDA folder
- [installed TensorRT](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-install-guide/index.html#installing-zip) 5.1.2.2 via the zip method and copied the relevant DLLs in CUDA again

This is the error:

```
> python
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

My PATH environment variable (I removed all non-Microsoft and non-NVidia entries):

```
> echo $env:PATH.Split(';')
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp
C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\
C:\Program Files\dotnet\
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.1\
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\extras\CUPTI\lib64
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\include
C:\Program Files\TensorRT-5.1.2.2\lib
C:\Program Files\TensorRT-5.1.2.2\bin
C:\tools\cuda\bin
```

TensorRT is installed in `C:\Program Files\TensorRT-5.1.2.2`.

Content of the CUDA `bin` folder:

```
PS C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin> ls


    Directory: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       18/04/2019     12:39                crt
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57         202752 bin2c.exe
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57       74850816 cublas64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57       36055552 cublasLt64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57         374272 cuda-memcheck.exe
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        4320256 cudafe++.exe
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57         339968 cudart32_101.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57         408064 cudart64_101.dll
-a----       18/04/2019     15:19      392566784 cudnn64_7.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57      115644416 cufft64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57         225792 cufftw64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        4785664 cuinj64_101.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        2074624 cuobjdump.exe
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57       49030656 curand64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57      171052032 cusolver64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57       87930368 cusparse64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57         285184 fatbinary.exe
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        1323008 gpu-library-advisor.exe
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57         233472 nppc64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57       10049024 nppial64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        3719680 nppicc64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        1003008 nppicom64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        7227904 nppidei64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57       46016512 nppif64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57       24603136 nppig64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        5848064 nppim64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57       17426944 nppist64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57         194560 nppisu64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        2610688 nppitc64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        8202240 npps64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57         247296 nvblas64_10.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57         384000 nvcc.exe
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57            310 nvcc.profile
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57       22919168 nvdisasm.exe
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57      149298688 nvgraph64_10.dll
-a----       18/04/2019     16:46      131539456 nvinfer.dll
-a----       18/04/2019     16:46        3663360 nvinfer_plugin.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        5960192 nvlink.exe
-a----       18/04/2019     16:46        4457472 nvonnxparser.dll
-a----       18/04/2019     16:46        2447872 nvparsers.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        4243456 nvprof.exe
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57         221696 nvprune.exe
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        4580352 nvrtc-builtins64_101.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57       15659520 nvrtc64_101_0.dll
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57             53 nvvp.bat
-a----       09/02/2019     06:57        5838336 ptxas.exe
```

And the content of `C:\tools`:

```
PS C:\tools> tree /F
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 6A54-3EA7
C:.
└───cuda
    │   NVIDIA_SLA_cuDNN_Support.txt
    │
    ├───bin
    │       cudnn64_7.dll
    │
    ├───include
    │       cudnn.h
    │
    └───lib
        └───x64
                cudnn.lib
```

Comment: Did you try [link](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&ei=eam4XJfjGeyJggfltLqgCg&q=ImportError%3A+DLL+load+failed%3A+The+specified+module+could+not+be+found.+in+windows+while+installing+tensorflow&oq=ImportError%3A+DLL+load+failed%3A+The+specified+module+could+not+be+found.+in+windows+while+installing+tensorflow&gs_l=psy-ab.3...82480.90069..90398...0.0..0.115.1697.29j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0j0i30.diPzYN5IZ7M) ?

Comment: @user1410665 Yes. Some fixed it by using Anaconda which I don't want to use, or installing specific versions of libraries but since TensorFlow has changed versions since then the numbers aren't right anymore. I was hoping that someone would have a better solution than trying all possible version combinations by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I installed CUDA 10.1 instead of 10.0. TensorFlow isn't yet compatible with 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some versions of TensorFlow doesn't support CUDA 10.1, in that case, CUDA 10.0 or lower version will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i resolved it, If you are using pip or pip3 you have less chance succeeding in first time.

- Uninstall Python,CUDA, CuNN, Tensorflow-gpu (if you already installed)
- Install ANACONDA or MINICONDA
- Open ANACONDA prompt and run following command:

conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu

- This will create an environment tf_gpu whcih will install all compatible versions of Python, CUDA, CuNN and Tensorflow
- once all the packages installed open the ANACONDA prompt and type the following command

conda activate tf_gpu

- This will change the conda '(base)' to '(tf_gpu)' environment
- Then type python as usual to activate the python prompt
- If you want to deactivate the 'tf_gpu' environment

conda deactivate