# CUDA DLL not working within Conda enviornment

Tags: python, conda

I was working on using the Simple Transformers python library from [here](https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers) when I got a Windows error with following error when running the example code on the import statement `from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel`:

"The procedure entry point cusparseGetErrorString could not be located in the dynamic link library cusparse64_10.dll"

I've tried reinstalling the relevant within the Conda environment as described on the GitHub, reinstalling CUDA itself and running a registry cleaner but I haven't been able to help this issue and I've run out of ideas to approach this, so I would appreciate any help.

CUDA has been working fine for me outside of Conda environments previously.

Comment: Do you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55749305/dll-load-failed-when-importing-tensorflow-with-gpu-support/55753291) issue? The Cuda driver needs to be install properly.

Comment: Please provide the contents of the environment.